# Liferay 7 Can't add empty Web content display or Form

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I can't add normally a web content display or other portlet like form etc ...

I am using **LIFERAY 7** and **Hypersonic** as database

[Here is a gif image that shows the problem](https://img4.hostingpics.net/pics/78622720170530132922.gif)

Comment: It could because of the layout, no content, error, etc - difficult to guess. Turn on the toggle mode with developer tools to find if you can provide any additional information.

Comment: I've done it but no visual errors

Comment: Set your log to debug mode and see if that helps.

Comment: The log console doesn't display anything , i set debug mode and developper mode ( liferay config)...

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the portal. Clear browser cache. Try adding the portlets to new page. This shall help.

Comment: I tried it and also forcing garbage collector and  clearing servlet, vm, and cluster cache but it still the same ...